# Is there a version of python that we can change dictionary size during iteration?

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration, runtime-error, version

This is my code and I wrote this in my computer science test.

```
di={'1':[1],'2':[2],'3':[1,2,3,4],'4':[4,5,6]}
print(di)
for i in di:
    if len(di[i])>=2: del di[i]
print(di)
```

In the current python version my code throws an error.
-> RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

The professor said that it is correct if my code works on a different or older version of Python, but is there a version of Python that my code works on?

I searched a lot on the internet but couldn't find an answer that worked for me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn6TJ.png)

According to the above article, there is a version, but I don't know which version it is specifically.

Comment: Never try to change the size of of whatever you're iterating over. I'm surprised this worked in an older version of Python. It certainly won't work now or in the future. Iterate over a copy of the dictionary - i.e., *for i in di.copy():*

Comment: According to that article there is a method. That's not a version. It looks to me like a different algorithm that avoids the problem. The problem is easily fixed in the code you have: create a copy of the dictionary. Unless this is crucially important for your course, don't waste time on this. Learn from your mistake and move on.

Comment: What "above article"?

Comment: it is a bad practice to change the size of the iterable while looping over it. This is why you get runtime Error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few methods to avoid Runtime error:

1.using list

```
di={'1':[1],'2':[2],'3':[1,2,3,4],'4':[4,5,6]}
print(di)
for i in list(di):
    if len(di[i])>=2: 
        del di[i]
print(di)
```

2.using copy()

```
di={'1':[1],'2':[2],'3':[1,2,3,4],'4':[4,5,6]}
print(di)
for i in di.copy():
    if len(di[i])>=2: 
        del di[i]
print(di)

#output
{'1': [1], '2': [2], '3': [1, 2, 3, 4], '4': [4, 5, 6]}
{'1': [1], '2': [2]}
```